# node.js parse form data form HTTP request

Tags: node.js, stream, request

I have some question about parse form data.
My solution is

```
aReq.pipe(parseFilesOrFields())
files.pipe(doFilesLogicStream())
fileds.pipe(otherLogicStream())
```

But i don't know how to parse data on stream.

```
req.on('data',(chunk)=>{
  if(chunk.filename){
    fileStream()
  }
    fieldStream()
})
```

and  also need fileStream and fieldStream will be promise --.